# How do I fix the "incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int" error

Tags: java

I have what I think should work but Java doesn't like it.

I get this error:

```
project5.java:10: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int

int Low = Math.sqrt(count);
                   ^1 error
```

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*
public class project5
{
   public static void main (String args[])
   {
      int count = 1;
      while (count < 11) {
          Random r = new Random();
          int Low = Math.sqrt(count);
          int High = count;
          int Result = r.nextInt(High-Low) + Low;
          System.out.println( count + "\t" + Math.sqrt(count));
          count++;
       }
   }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `Math.sqrt` returns double and you are using `int`.

Comment: Do you really expect the result from Math.sqrt(2) to be an int? Math.sqrt(3)...? ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just cast the result to `int`:

```
int Low = (int) Math.sqrt(count);
```

This works good enough, if you are fine with taking floor from result. If you want it rounded, then do

```
(int) Math.round(Math.sqrt(count));
```

It's safe to cast to `int` in this particular case, as `count` is an `int` and `sqrt` of it always fits in `int` range.

Comment: @JustanotherITGuy so please accept my answer if it works :)

Answer (score 0):

cast the sqrt to int, you will lose the decimal part...

```
 int Low = (int) Math.sqrt(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates you are trying to assign a `double` to an `int`.

The `Math.sqrt` method returns a double: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#sqrt(double)

If you want to assign this to an integer, you can simply cast it to an integer as such:

```
int Low = (int)Math.sqrt(count);
```

Note: in case the result of the `sqrt` method is not a whole number, casting the result to an integer will assign the whole part of the result to the integer:

```
System.out.println(String.valueOf((int)Math.sqrt(5))); // Prints 2
```